# Firebase services conflict

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Some times my application crash when I build my project using the firebase firestore and firebase storage dependencies togheter, it's something sporadic, how can I fix this? I need to use some specific version?

My pubspec.xml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:  
  firebase_storage:  <------ The crashes begun when I add this firebase_storage dependencie
  sqflite:
  flutter_map: "^0.1.4"
  date_format: "^1.0.4"
  image_picker: 
  google_maps_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins
      path: packages/google_maps_flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

I think that the application crash when I call

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot){
.....
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this

```
await Firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
```

[GitHub problem](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18159)

[GitHub example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/example/lib/main.dart#L22)